# fetch api from expo react native gives Ty[eerror: network failed connection

Tags: mongodb, react-native, expo, fetch, fetch-api

im tryinf to build a signup page with phone number with mongodb and the database is connected with nodejs successfully but when i try to submit data from the use it throws this error:

> Typeerror: network connection failed

Signup.js page
this is the signup screen it contains submitData method to fetch the data from API and save the new submit values

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Button,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ActivityIndicator,
} from "react-native";
import EvilIcons from "@expo/vector-icons/EvilIcons";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import AppLoader from "../component/AppLoader";
export default function Signup() {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const [phone, setPhone] = useState("");
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const submitData = () => {
    fetch("http://10.0.2.2:3000/send-data", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        phone: phone,
      }),
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        alert("Done");
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        alert(err);
      });
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.text1}>Welcome To Gamifier CheckIn</Text>
      <Text style={styles.text2}> Type your number and become our guest!</Text>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.inputBox}
        placeholder="  +966"
        onChangeText={(phone) => setPhone({ phone })}
      />
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => submitData() && navigation.navigate("Rewards1")}
      >
        <EvilIcons name="arrow-right" size={55} color="#FBBD0A"></EvilIcons>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

App.js server

```js
type hconst express = require('express');
const app =  express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const mongURL =
  "mongodb+srv://checkIn-admin:tAGaZ7sp38Qw43oG@cluster0.odzlhm2.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

require("./User");
const User = mongoose.model("User");
app.use(bodyParser.json());

mongoose.connect(mongURL, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

mongoose.connection.on("connected", () => {
  console.log("Connected Successfully!");
});
mongoose.connection.on("error", (err) => {
  console.log("error", err);
});

app.post("/update", (req, res) => {
  User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.id, {
    phone: req.body.phone,
  })
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      res.send(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("error", err);
    });
});

app.post("/send-data", (req, res) => {
  const user = new User({
    phone: req.body.phone,
  });
  user
    .save()
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      res.send(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
});
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  User.find({})
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      res.send(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
});
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Listening on 3000 ");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the below options it may be working.

**1.** Check your network security config setting that http request should be allowed.

**2.** check your machine IP address and try with that. localhost of your machine cannot be accessed from another machine. if you want to access localhost then both of your machine must be connected to same network.

**3.** The last option is that use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/download) to access your localhost from anywhere . it will generate 2 link to your localhost one is http and second one is https and u can your both of them to call your api.

Comment: Thank you it's work but is there any way to make the link work permanently?

Comment: you can signup to get a link that work for whole session. if you want a permanent link then you have to pay for it.